# Kafka connector config error: filter.condition: Invalid json path defined

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, jsonpath, debezium

I'm trying to use Confluent's [Filter SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/filter.html) with Debezium example [unwrap-smt](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/master/unwrap-smt).

I added the following configs to source connector (Debezium MySQL) config:

```
    "transforms": "route,csFilter",
    ...
    ...
    "transforms.csFilter.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
    "transforms.csFilter.filter.condition": "$.payload.after.source == 2",
    "transforms.csFilter.filter.type": "exclude",
    "transforms.csFilter.missing.or.null.behavior": "fail"
```

Since this Filter SMT is provided by Confluent, I downloaded the [jar file](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/connect-transforms) and copied (connect-transforms, connect-utils, json-path) jar files to `path-to-kafka/connect/debezium-connector-mysql` directory.

When I tried to register Debezium MySQL source connector,

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
localhost:8083/connectors/ -d @source_connector_config.json
```

I got this error:

```
{"error_code":400,
"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\n
Invalid value $.payload.after.source == 2 for configuration filter.condition: Invalid json path defined. 
Please refer to https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath README for correct use of json path.\n
You can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}
```

I checked the JSON path expression with the examples provided in [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath). It seemed okay.

Can you please point me to the right directioin? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Try this condition: `$.payload.after[?(@.source == 2)]`

Comment: It worked. "after" property of the JSON data does not have any list. Can you please explain why we have subscript operator [] in the json path expression? Also, if you can copy the solution as an answer, I'll accept it as answer. Thanks!

Comment: Please check the [docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators): Filter expressions need brackets. Example: https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath#1-getting-object-data-given-ids

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander, I'm having similar issue, could you please help me to resolve my issue. here is the post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282697/how-to-filter-and-insert-new-filed-in-kafka-http-sink-connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to use this condition: `$.payload.after[?(@.source == 2)]`