# Filter condition not working in kafka http sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, jsonpath

I'm using confluent kafka http sink connector, I want to filter this condition - if `item.productID=12` then allow this event or ignore. But my filter condition not working

`"transforms.filterExample1.filter.condition": "$.[*][?(@.item.productID == '12')]",`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.http.HttpSinkConnector",
    "confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "topics": "http-messages",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "http.api.url": "http://localhost:8080/api/messages",
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
    "transforms.filter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
    "transforms": "filterExample1",
    "transforms.filterExample1.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter$Value",
    "transforms.filterExample1.filter.condition": "$.[*][?(@.item.productID == '12')]",
    "transforms.filterExample1.filter.type": "include",
    "transforms.filterExample1.missing.or.null.behavior": "fail",
    "reporter.error.topic.name": "error-responses",
    "reporter.result.topic.name": "success-responses",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "confluent.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "name": "HttpSink",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1"
}
```

**My Event**

```
[
   {
      "name":"apple",
      "salary":"3243",
      "item":{
         "productID":"12"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. A filter will not help you insert a field within an element of an array. Are you saying you get data with other product ids?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Sorry for the confusion. I edited my post, I just want to filter some condition, my json expression is not working for some reason. Could you please check and help me - what i'm missing in this condition. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it here and it worked fine - https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com

Comment: Yes in  jsonpath.herokuapp.com is working but same thing not working from connector config.

Comment: You might want to change `transforms.filter.type` to `transforms. filterExample1.type` since that is the correct transform name

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in a JSON array, this transform wont work.

Tested with local data using the latest version of that transform, and saw this log from the Connect server

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [filtering record without schema], found: java.util.ArrayList
  at io.confluent.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireMap(Requirements.java:30) ~[?:?]
  at io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter.shouldDrop(Filter.java:218) ~[?:?]
  at io.confluent.connect.transforms.Filter.apply(Filter.java:161) ~[?:?]
```

"Map Objects" implying JSON objects

Also, you have a setting `transforms.filter.type` that's not doing anything

Comment: Thank for the quick response ..but my producer send data in JSON list, how can I handle this?

Comment: Remove the transform and use other steam processing libraries to filter the data

Comment: sorry I'm not finding any other library which does the filter in connector, most the page recommends this link only https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html Sorry I'm new to kafka confluent- could u pls recommend some library which can used in connector config and fits for my above JSON payload. Appreciated your help on this!

Comment: No, I meant use Kafka Streams, KSQL, a regular consumer with an if statement. Anything other than connect should be able to filter that data. Only downside is you'll have two topics. One with all the connector data and another with the filtered data

Comment: Alternatively, edit your HTTP server to accept query/body parameters that perform the filter instead

Comment: Thank you! I'll see how can we write Kafka stream to filter this data. You mentioned you are getting this error Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [filtering record without schema], found: java.util.ArrayList
 in connector log - how to view he connector log? And wondering why Kafka confluent is not supporting the basic JSON list while filtering the data :(

Comment: If you're using Confluent Cloud, I'm not sure how to see logs, but that error is also in the /status endpoint of the Connector. And you'd have to open a support ticket with Confluent since that Filter transform isn't open source